# Same JS obfuscator features like this one

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

Does someone know if there is an ASP.net library or EXE that obfuscate Javascript like http://javascriptobfuscator.com/default.aspx. I need the same features. I like the obfuscator because when I try to throw it to a beautifier it still very hard to read. Others can be easily reversed engineered to the same code as before. The one on javascriptobfuscator.com does a better job.

It doesn't offer a downloadable version, so maybe you know where I can find one that does the same. I've read other questions but didn't find one that do that.

Comment: Our obfuscators' output is arguably hard to read even if prettyprinted: http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Obfuscators/ECMAScriptObfuscator.html Size matters; if you only obfuscate a few lines, no obfuscator will do much that is useful.  If you obfuscate a lot of code, then it gets pretty hard to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a cheap obfuscator, uglifyjs can easily beautify the obfuscated javascript.

Here is the example beautified:

```
function MsgBox(b) {
    alert(b + _0x1495[1] + a);
}

var _0x1495 = [ "Hello World!", "\n", "OK" ], a = _0x1495[0];

MsgBox(_0x1495[2]);
```

I think it's pretty easy to read.

Comment: any other suggestions, something that will make the "thief"'s life a bit harder